# How to get links from a collection of users

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection of users

```
$department = Department::find(1)->users;
```

I need to get Journal relations to them, the code below is working, but here the conditions are used directly from the `Users` table, and I specifically need from the `$department` collection

```
User::where('name', '<>', 'Manager')
        ->with(['journal' => function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('schedule', 'like', "%" . $request->date . "%");
    }])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$department = Department::with('users.journal')
        ->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', '<>', 'Manager')->whereHas('journal', function ($q) use ($request) {
                $q->where('schedule', 'like', "%" . $request->date . "%");
            });
        })->find(1);
```

Comment: Please tell me when trying to use it return JournalResource::collection($department); I get an error Call to undefined method App\Models\Department::mapInto()

Comment: can u upload your JournalResource class and DepartmentResource class ?